# Corda - Crypto.doVerify never returns false

Tags: corda

I just found this code in Corda's crypto API for handling key verification:

```
fun doVerify(signatureScheme: SignatureScheme, publicKey: PublicKey, signatureData: ByteArray, clearData: ByteArray): Boolean {
    require(Crypto.isSupportedSignatureScheme(signatureScheme)) {
        "Unsupported key/algorithm for schemeCodeName: ${signatureScheme.schemeCodeName}"
    }
    if (signatureData.isEmpty()) throw IllegalArgumentException("Signature data is empty!")
    if (clearData.isEmpty()) throw IllegalArgumentException("Clear data is empty, nothing to verify!")
    val verificationResult = Crypto.isValid(signatureScheme, publicKey, signatureData, clearData)
    if (verificationResult) {
        return true
    } else {
        throw SignatureException("Signature Verification failed!")
    }
}
```

I can understand throwing exceptions when arguments are invalid, but I'm curious as to why this either returns true, or throws another exception when `verificationResult` is `false`, rather than just `return verificationResult`. This seems like a highly unusual design choice!

Could someone, ideally from the R3 engineering team explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No engineering team here, but I guess it is because `Crypto.doVerify` is the function called from `TransactionSignature.verify`, which is the one used in the flows to verify the signatures. Raising an exception in such an essential function, allows the flow to wrap it to a `FlowException` so that it can be managed by the [Flow Hospital](https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.5/node-flow-hospital.html#flow-hospital).

Comment: Understood, however a better design would have been to either have a `requireVerify` method that either throws or continues, or to throw the wrapped exception from the `TransactionSignature.verify` method instead.